# ValueError: The following arguments have not been supplied: email

Tags: python, flask, cron, apscheduler

I have the following route that upon POST request performs a certain task & increase count by 1.

```
@blueprint.route("Calendar", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Calendar(): 
    count +=1
    email = request.json.get('email') 
    therestart(email)
    return email
```

I'd like to reset the count every 24 hours per individual user basis, so the best way that came to my mind was to do a background scheduler:

```
import atexit
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def therestart(email):
        if email:
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
            user.count = 0
        return 'no email'
    
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=therestart, trigger="interval", seconds=200) #change to 86400 sec in prod
scheduler.start()
```

which gives an error:

```
ValueError: The following arguments have not been supplied: email
```

which makes sense but at the same time, if I were to change it to something like this:

```
def therestart(email):
    if email:
        scheduler()
def scheduler()
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(func=therestart, trigger="interval", seconds=3) 
    scheduler.start()
```

then every time email gets passed or activated, `scheduler()` performs which is against my goal.

Would really appreciate if someone can save me from this dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a value for the *email* argument in your target function. So you need to use either **args** or **kwargs** for that. Hence, you can do something like this:

```
def therestart(*args):
    if len(args)>0:
        email = args[0]
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        user.count = 0
    return 'no email'
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I did that and got: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/Users/Daniyal/Startup/Website/app/base/routes.py", line 464, in therestart
    email = args[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: You have used **if email**, right? So as per my guess there might be some cases in which you are not recieving an email. Maybe coz of that index error is coming. For the values in which *therestart* func is not getting any email value. Try working around this. Otherwise you have to pass email as an *args or as **kwargs.

Comment: After every *x* amount of seconds, **therestart** is getting executed by the scheduler. *args will contain any value only when the API gets hit. When API is not getting hit and **therestart** func gets executed by the scheduler, the *args is an empty tuple. That is on doing *email = args[0]*, index error comes. I am editing the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive solution! That definitely did fix it. I ended up going with my own solution as posted, as it required less dependency with fewer lines.

Comment: Upon upvote, I got "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing:

```
def restart():
    users = User.query.all()
    for user in users:
        if user.stripeSubscriptionId is None:
            user.count = 1
            db.session.commit()
    return ''
```